# Aptana Studio 3 - Synchronize Subfolder

Tags: ftp, aptana, publish

Is it possible to setup a subfolder of a project in Aptana Studio to synchronize with an FTP site?  I have a project that contains multiple subfolders, only one of which is the actual web application.  I want to sync my application folder with my server via FTP.  It appears that the synchronize tool in Aptana uses the Project folder as the root for synchronization.

Comment: I usually make a (sub)project of just the web application folder and only use the main project when I need to.

Comment: I'm not familiar with sub projects in Aptana.  How can I do that?

Comment: When I say (sub)project I just mean a normal project that happens to reference a folder inside of an existing project. For instance, I have a project for a WAMP installation, then I have one for each virtual host inside the `www` folder. Working on the vhosts individually I use their projects, and I only open the overall WAMP project when I need to change server configuration values.